# Strange Texture array buffer limitations

Tags: opengl-es, floating-point, webgl

Within a WebGl fragment shader I'm using a texture generated from an array of 32bit values but it yields errors when going above a resolution of 7000x7000px this is far below the maximum texture resolution for my gpu 16384x16384px. gl.Unsigned works without issue at higher resolutions but not so when changed to gl.float .  Is this a known limitation when dealing with floats? Are there work arounds? any input much appreciated.

my texture parameters -
"gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, 8192, 8192, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.FLOAT, Z_pixels)"

Answer (score 1):

7000*7000*32 bits per float*4 ~= 784 megabytes of memory. Perhaps that exceeded your graphic card memory capacity?

As per MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302435(v=vs.85).aspx says "[gl.FLOAT] creates 128 bit-per-pixel textures instead of 32 bit-per-pixel for the image." so its possible that gl.ALPHA will still use 128 bits per pixel.

Comment: 7000*7000*32 bits per float ~= 196 megabytes